# How to change file creation time in the different file systems

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-management, fat32

Is there a tool that would allow me to change the file creation time and file modified time on a list of files?

Must be able to work in the NTFS and FAT32 file systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Total Commander is of course the answer to all file management problems! However if you only want to change dates (and other file properties), [**Better File Attributes**](http://www.publicspace.net/windows/BetterFileAttributes/index.html) is a cheaper alternative.

[image: Better File Attributes]

It's a shell extension (added to the context menu of files) that allows you to change creation, access and modification date and time.

If you want a freeware application, **[SetFileDate](http://no-nonsense-software.com/freeware/)** will do the trick too.

[image: SetFileDate]

Comment: How can this be done without installing any third-party software, using just the Windows operating system?

Answer (score 18):

This can be done by using powershell to modify a list of FileInfo objects, for example:

```
Get-ChildItem G:\test\*.bak | foreach { $_.CreationTime = get-date "1/1/1982 1:00 pm"; $_.LastWriteTime = (get-date).AddDays(-1)}
```

Answer (score 8):

[Total Commander](http://ghisler.com/) enables you to change creation date and time for a file.

- select one or more files
- select menu Files -> Change attributes
- in lower part of the form that opened click More attributes button
- for property select creationdate to change time and date (creatiotime if you only want to change time)
- click on >> button and enter value for date and time you want, then click OK

Comment: [Double Commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/) can do the same and is free.

Answer (score 1):

[BulkFileChanger](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html) is a pretty nifty free utility as well!

[image: BulkFileChanger]

Of course there are also many advanced command-line file touch utilities as well that you can use in scripts, batch files and the like (such as [this](http://www.wintestgear.com/products/FileTouch/FileTouch.html) and [this](http://www.softtreetech.com/24x7/archive/47.htm)).