# Windows 7 filesystem: Flabbergasted - Delete and recreate file: creation time does not change! Why and how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs

I need to update the *creation time* of a bogus file to 'now', by deleting it and recreating it. Strangely, the newly created file looks like it inherits the original file's creation time!

Let me demonstrate:

```
> touch a.txt       //create a new file
> dir /T:C          //creation time
02/27/2013  02:04 PM                 0 a.txt

> dir /T:W          //modification time
02/27/2013  02:04 PM                 0 a.txt

//wait a bit...
> touch a.txt       //update modified-time
> dir /T:C
02/27/2013  02:04 PM                 0 a.txt

> dir /T:W          //mod-time changed, as expected
02/27/2013  02:05 PM                 0 a.txt

> del a.txt
> touch a.txt       //recreate file
> dir /T:C          //same original ctime !!
02/27/2013  02:04 PM                 0 a.txt

> dir /T:W          //the actual time the 2nd file was created
02/27/2013  02:06 PM                 0 a.txt

> del a.txt
> touch b.txt       //ok, create a file with a different name
> dir /T:C          //ctime as expected
02/27/2013  02:07 PM                 0 b.txt

> mv b.txt a.txt
> dir /T:C          //again, ctime of original file!
02/27/2013  02:04 PM                 0 a.txt

> del a.txt
> touch c.txt       //create a file with a different name, again
> dir /T:C          //ctime as expected
02/27/2013  02:08 PM                 0 c.txt

> cp c.txt a.txt    //this time copy it...
> dir /T:C          //ctime of a.txt is that of original file!
02/27/2013  02:04 PM                 0 a.txt
02/27/2013  02:08 PM                 0 c.txt

//wait longer...

> del *
> touch d.txt
> dir /T:C
02/27/2013  02:22 PM                 0 d.txt

> cp d.txt a.txt
> dir /T:C          //lo and behold, the ctime has changed.
02/27/2013  02:22 PM                 0 a.txt
02/27/2013  02:22 PM                 0 d.txt
```

This concludes my demonstration. Two questions arise:

[image: WTF ?!]

1. ^^^ What he said.
2. How can I fix it?

Ok, let me expand on these:

1. Does anyone know what internal mechanics of the Windows OS / NTFS are at play? It looks like some file metadata caching takes place, and the cache invalidation is time-bound.
2. Any suggestions on how I can get a brand-new file of the same name as an original, with an up-to-date `ctime`? Any suggestions are welcome, be they batch scripts, registry hacks, programmatic or what-have-you.

Comment: This has been asked before it seems: http://superuser.com/questions/71962/how-to-change-file-creation-time-in-the-different-file-systems?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. However, that answers the *how* (kind of), but not the *why*.

Comment: Has to do with the fact the dates are not updated right away by design to prevent less write cycles on the storage device. Which is the exact reason I pointed you to the question I did.

Comment: Raymond Chen explains this in his blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/15/439261.aspx

Comment: @Kryten Broken link, this works: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050715-14/?p=34923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers:

1. The process is called 'File System Tunneling' (derived from quantum mechanics) and, as far as I understand, it was originally designed for win 95. It is necessary for operating system to handle the situation when a program just saves and overwrites a file. A that case the user usually expects that creation date (and short file name) doesn't change, but without tunneling the creation date would reflect the last save time. See: [Some reminders about Windows file times](https://laserkittens.com/some-reminders-about-windows-file-times), [The apocryphal history of file system tunnelling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050715-14/?p=34923)
2. There are two ways of fixing the problem:

- by immediate modification of the creation time after saving/creation
- by registry settings (for whole operating system):

> The file tunneling settings are controlled by the Windows Registry key
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem.
>
> To increase the tunneling cache time, modify/add the DWORD value
> MaximumTunnelEntryAgeInSeconds. The default cache time is 15 seconds.
> To disable tunneling, modify/add the DWORD value MaximumTunnelEntries
> and set it to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Windows, but I think I've found a workaround.

1. Win32 apparently allows [modifying file creation times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using the [SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
2. If you're not writing an app with Win32, you should be able to use PowerShell.  Based on a [similar stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7363062/799204):

   ```
   C:\> powershell  (ls your-file-name-here).CreationTime = Get-Date
   ```

Comment: That's great. I need to learn PowerShell...

Answer (score 0):

Use atime, not ctime. Access time is effectively the creation time
as it is not updated on access [anymore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_times)

Comment: Turns out the craziness has a name. It is called [tunneling](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172190).

Comment: Why are you linking to a Wikipedia article that says "This article's factual accuracy is disputed."? In any case it doesn't answer the question.